# How to remove twbs folder in my Laravel project?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, laravel, laravel-5.4, twitter-bootstrap-4

I don't know how to use twbs in my Laravel project. So how can I delete this folder?

[image]

composer.json

```
{
    "name": "laravel/laravel",
    "description": "The Laravel Framework.",
    "keywords": ["framework", "laravel"],
    "license": "MIT",
    "type": "project",
    "require": {
        "php": ">=5.6.4",
        "laravel/framework": "5.4.*",
        "laravel/tinker": "~1.0",
        "twbs/bootstrap": "4.0.0"
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "fzaninotto/faker": "~1.4",
        "mockery/mockery": "0.9.*",
        "phpunit/phpunit": "~5.7"
    },
    "autoload": {
        "classmap": [
            "database"
        ],
        "psr-4": {
            "App\\": "app/"
        }
    },
    "autoload-dev": {
        "psr-4": {
            "Tests\\": "tests/"
        }
    },
    "scripts": {
        "post-root-package-install": [
            "php -r \"file_exists('.env') || copy('.env.example', '.env');\""
        ],
        "post-create-project-cmd": [
            "php artisan key:generate"
        ],
        "post-install-cmd": [
            "Illuminate\\Foundation\\ComposerScripts::postInstall",
            "php artisan optimize"
        ],
        "post-update-cmd": [
            "Illuminate\\Foundation\\ComposerScripts::postUpdate",
            "php artisan optimize"
        ]
    },
    "config": {
        "preferred-install": "dist",
        "sort-packages": true,
        "optimize-autoloader": true
    }
}
```

Comment: where is the folder located? in which directory?

Comment: ' Vendor\twbs '

Comment: @Chirag_php add require part from composer json

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The good idea is to use `composer remove` command without updating all other packages:

```
composer remove twbs/bootstrap
```

Comment: @Chirag_php if you want help, please show the full error message you get and `composer.json` contents. Also, have you deleted files from the folder manually?

Comment: fewagency/twbs-blade is not required in your composer.json and has not been removed
Package "fewagency/twbs-blade" listed for update is not installed. Ignoring.
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
Nothing to install or update
Generating optimized autoload files
> Illuminate\Foundation\ComposerScripts::postUpdate
> php artisan optimize
Generating optimized class loader
The compiled services file has been removed.

Comment: @Chirag_php please show the `composer.json` file. You can edit your question and add the file contents to the original question.

Comment: @Chirag_php it looks like you've shown only part of the `composer.json`

Comment: But, also give mr a answer of how to use `TWBS` ??

Comment: @Chirag_php I haven't use the package, so I can't answer that. I might want to start from reading docs for the package.

Answer (score 1):

Remove `"twbs/bootstrap": "4.0.0"` line from `composer.json` and then `run` command:

```
composer update
```

Comment: could you please share your `composer.json` file??

Comment: yes.!! but first of i remove twbs after 'composer update' comand run then also this twbs also update.

Comment: you want to remove twbs folder from vendor, right?? please show your `composer.json` file

Comment: How to share ? im new in stackoverflow.

Comment: copy all your code from composer.json and paste here in your question

Comment: @Chirag_php see my updated answer, this will work for you too. remember one thing, always add complete information about your problem in the questions

Answer (score 0):

Run This command For Remove any package

> **`composer remove twbs/bootstrap`**